# ul li elements have more space in between in IE than firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I am facing interoperability issues in IE7 and Firefox. li elements height is somewhat more in IE than Firefox.

Here is the attached image for more clarity.

[image: interop]
http://img225.imageshack.us/i/interop.jpg/

Code for html and CSS:

```
<ul class="sa-progress">
<li class="sa-progress-current"><span id="intro_idx" >Select VPN Type</span></li>
<li class="sa-progress-default"><span id="local_idx" >Local</span></li>
<li class="sa-progress-default"><span id="remote_idx" >Remote</span></li>
<li class="sa-progress-default"><span id="vpn_idx" >VPN</span></li>
<li class="sa-progress-default"><span id="remote_dyn_idx" >Remote Users</span></li>
<li class="sa-progress-default"><span id="traffic_idx" >Traffic Profile</span></li>
<li class="sa-progress-default"><span id="review_idx" >Review &amp; Commit</span></li>
</ul>

ul.sa-progress {
    color: #333333;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 7px 0 10px 10px;
}
ul.sa-progress {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Please let me know what am missing here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ul/li is one of the more common cross browser differences that crop up as they both have different interpretations of their default rules.

You should look into using a css reset sheet to start off with such as:

- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/

This will apply consistent base rules to your formatting so that all browsers have a fair chance at matching.

Because you didn't start out with this reset stylesheet and then build your design on top of it you might find that applying it will make several other elements go a bit different when they react to the new defaults. I would say its better to fix these so they look right with the reset sheet and then you will have a consistent baseline to work from.

After that you still might have problems but from the css you have posted I think there are some more parts to it such as the double line spacing you have in some menu items.

If you are going to make these into menu items then a common way that I approach this kind of styling is to make the a tags `display: block;` and then work my spacings out from that. Try to keep your ul li stylings as lightweight as possible and work with other items you have (such as the container div for the menu and the anchor tags for the links).